# Facebook Ads API: transaction_detail?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

Facebook currently supports the ability to list the transactions that occur on an Ad Account through their API (although its very hard to find):

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/act_{{ACCOUNT_ID}}/transactions

```
     {
        "id": "{{TRANSACTION_ID}}-1399450",
        "time": 1438255264,
        "account_id": "{{ACCOUNT_ID}}",
        "fatura_id": 0,
        "amount": {
            "currency": "CAD",
            "total_amount": "2,100.40"
        },
        "charge_type": "payment",
        "status": "completed",
        "billing_start_time": 0,
        "billing_end_time": 0,
        "payment_option": "credit_card",
        "tx_type": 3,
        "app_amount": {
            "currency": "CAD",
            "amount": "2,100.40"
        },
        "provider_amount": {
            "currency": "CAD",
            "amount": "2,100.40"
        }
    }
```

However, if you notice, there's nothing in there about the Payment ID, thus making it very difficult to figure out what the heck this transaction/payment is for... nothing tiing to ads, adsets, campaigns, anything!

If anyone has any recommendations as to how to get more specific information about a transaction, I would love the help!

Also - just to note that if I used my APP_ID token (because it claims I can't do it from a user access token, which misleads me to think I was actually getting somewhere!) and ping the transaction id as such:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/{{TRANSACTION_ID}}

I get:

```
    {
    "error": {
"message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
"type": "GraphMethodException",
"code": 100
   }
 }
```

Which is how you can apparently inspect payments from within canvas payments, but this is specifically for Ad accounts payments/transactions.

Comment: There is no direct link between a transaction you made on the account and what you used it on. i.e. if fund the account in two transactions, A and B, and pay for a campaign, which transaction provided the funds for the payment? there is no such relation right now.

Comment: I believe the relation is there, the endpoint isn't exposed. When you go through the facebook billing area, and see the transactions, there's an internal API call that shows the transactions according to an order_id, it just doesn't make sense to me that this would not be exposed on their marketing api.